# SQL Updating multiple rows in one join

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables

```
old_id  | category_id
---------------------
45      | 3455
45      | 07072
38      | 0293

old_id  | new_id
----------------
45      | 1023
38      | 1027
```

In the first table the primary key is composite `(old_id, category_id)`. There may be multiple categories for each `old_id` as you can see `from old_id=45`.

How do I update every `old_id` row with the relevant `new_id`?

I'm using `MySQL 5.5`

Comment: Can you specify what is 'relevant new_id'?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41fa8/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join both tables in an `UPDATE` query.

Try this:

```
UPDATE TableOld a 
    JOIN TableNew b ON a.old_id = b.old_id
SET a.old_id= b.new_id
```

Comment: why you SET category_id = new_id?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that :

```
update t1 
set old_id = new_id
from t2
where t1.old_id = t2.old_id
```

Answer (score 0):

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41fa8/1)

```
UPDATE tab1 T1 SET T1.old_id = (
  SELECT T2.new_id FROM tab2 T2 
  WHERE t2.old_id = t1.old_id
);
```

Then you will get **tab1** output as

```
| OLD_ID | CATEGORY_ID |
|--------|-------------|
|   1023 |        3455 |
|   1023 |       07072 |
|   1027 |        0293 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON 
    TABLE1.old_id = TABLE2.old_id 
    SET TABLE1.old_id = TABLE2.new_id
```

Answer (score 0):

would this

```
UPDATE Table1 a 
    JOIN Table2 b ON a.old_id = b.old_id
    SET a.category_id= b.new_id
```